# Display data from web service using views

Tags: 7, views, database

I need to query data from a web service and display it in a view without storing the data in Drupal database. I am using [WSData module](https://www.drupal.org/project/wsdata) for this purpose but I am unable to figure out how and when the webservice is getting invoked. My web service doesn't have any parameters passed and it returns a list of items. I would like to display the list as a table using views.

It would be of great help if I can get any samples or references.

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/wsdata

This module allows you to bypass the default data storage location for fields and entities and instead load the data from a web service.

This is useful when your primary data source is in another system but you want to display/use this data in your Drupal site without the hassle of syncing or importing data.

Comment: As I mentioned in my query I am already using wsdata module. I am unable to find the documentation on how to integrate the data retrieved with Views module